# Query upon the specific function of .row class in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a question, might be a silly one, but it's making me curious!

Below is the link of my code in codepen.

First preview it in full-size, and then just add `row` in the class of `div` tag (on line number 11 of the html code) which would be `<div class=" row well well-lg">`. Now notice the changes that takes place

So... I am curious to know that what css property of .div class made that possible.

I wasted an hour digging but failed. If anyone can help me out I would really appreciate it.

[codepen-link](http://codepen.io/neel111/pen/dOBjOj?editors=1000)

Also it seems fine (with `.row` class) in small and extra-small size view as if the .row class is already being added.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```css
.well {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

for best understanding what happens when you add class `row` and when remove it.

If you'd have a look at "bootstrap.css", you'll see that there is predefined style for pseudo-selector:

```css
.row:before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
```

This statement defines new block formatting context, which makes element with class `row` to get common dimensions of those children, which don't make new BFC.

Class `well` doesn't have such kind of statement

You can make `well` to create new BFC (to behave almost as well as row) just adding `overflow: hidden` statement:

```css
.well {
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Look at **[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNvamE?editors=1100)**

P.S.: there are two articles for the theme:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ - trick used by bootstrap.

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/ - what is BFC and how it does work.

Comment: Yeah but when i add the code(given in teh end of the line) again, then the page must execute as it did without `.row` class being added.  `.row{display:block;}`

Comment: i mean after adding `row` in class of teh `div` tag, again add `.row{display:block;}` in the .css file. the page must look like the page of the 1st instance (when the `row` wasn't added in class of the div)

Comment: It will have the same look (either with row or without) when the cell have width of 100%, I mean `col-**-12`. Because of it your page has the same look with `row` and without it on small and extra-small viewports.

Comment: can you please elaborate it. actually i mean my page-without-row should look same like the page-with-row (by adding `.row{display:block}`)

Comment: `display:block` isn't the only attribute of `row` that affects on element. As it mentioned in the answer. `row:before` makes div height to depend on  heights of children and push down next row. without class `row` div will have minimal height that does not depend. **Bootstrap introduction:** Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Comment: I investigated your issue further and realized that `row` inherits its `:before`  style from class `clearfix` (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix). Thus if you'd put `clearfix` instead of `row`, then it has got the same effect